# PHP Tesseract SHELL_EXEC not working but working via Terminal

Tags: php, ubuntu, tesseract

I just wonder why I can't execute a tesseract command via PHP. The following command executed via terminal (my computer has got Ubuntu)

```
tesseract sample1.png reading
```

is working fine. While

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

$file = shell_exec('tesseract sample1.png reading');
echo "<pre>$file</pre>";
```

isn't working at all. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Appending  2>&1 to the command executes it. But gives the error:
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.

Comment: when running from terminal everything is fine, the environment variable is set correctly